# Reset cumsum if over limit (python)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The following numpy snippet will return a cumsum of the input array, which resets every time a NaN is encountered.

```
v = np.array([1., 1., 1., np.nan, 1., 1., 1., 1., np.nan, 1.])
n = np.isnan(v)
a = ~n
c = np.cumsum(a)
d = np.diff(np.concatenate(([0.], c[n])))
v[n] = -d
result = np.cumsum(v)
```

In a similar fashion, how can I calculate a cumsum which resets if the cumsum is over some value using vectorized pandas or numpy operations?

E.g. for limit = 5, in = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], out = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numbers in your array are all positive, it is probably simplest to use `cumsum()` and then the modulo operator:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
>>> limit = 5
>>> x = a.cumsum() % limit
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
```

You can then set any zero values back to the limit to get the desired array:

```
>>> x[x == 0] = limit
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

---

Here's one possible general solution using Pandas' `expanding_apply` method. (I've not tested it extensively...)

First define a modified `cumsum` function:

```
import pandas as pd

def cumsum_limit(x):
    q = np.sum(x[:-1])
    if q > 0:
        q = q%5
    r = x[-1]
    if q+r <= 5:
        return q+r
    elif (q+r)%5 == 0:
        return 5
    else:
        return (q+r)%5

a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]) # your example array
```

Apply the function to the array like this:

```
>>> pd.expanding_apply(a, lambda x: cumsum_limit(x))
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

Here's the function applied to another more interesting Series:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([3, -8, 4, 5, -3, 501, 7, -100, 98, 3])
>>> pd.expanding_apply(s, lambda x: cumsum_limit(x)) 
0     3
1    -5
2    -1
3     4
4     1
5     2
6     4
7   -96
8     2
9     5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Do you also have a modification which resets the cumulative sum after it has passed a limit, so adjusting the example slightly so it does not result in this

`>>> a = np.array([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])
>>> limit = 5
>>> x = a.cumsum() % limit
>>> x
array([2,4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1])`

but in this:

`array([2,4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4])`