# python pandas: group time series by cumsum defined value, reset sum if value is reached

Tags: python, pandas, reset, cumsum

I have a data frame with column A and B. 
Desired outcome:
If cumsum of B reaches value >=15, following operations for the rows between 0 and cumsum >=15 shall be computed: df["Amean"] =df["A"].mean() and df["Bsum15"] = df["B"].sum() ;
then cumsum shall be reset to 0 again and the loop continues.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXeXv.png)

similar topic:
[Python pandas cumsum() reset after hitting max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132757/python-pandas-cumsum-reset-after-hitting-max)

Comment: Why does the linked answer not answer your question, it seems to me to be an appropriate dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say, we take a simpler example

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],columns=['B'])


def accum(vals):
    acc=0
    for i in vals:
        acc+=i
        if acc>=15:
           yield acc
           acc=0
        else:
           yield np.nan

df['accu']=list(accum(df['B'].values))
```

returns

```
    B   accu
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
2   3   NaN
3   4   NaN
4   5   15.0
5   6   NaN
6   7   NaN
7   8   21.0
8   9   NaN
9   10  19.0
```