# Pandas : dataframe cumsum , reset if other column is false

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, cumsum

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, the objective here is simple ; reset the df.cumsum() if a row column is set to False;

> df

```
      value      condition
0       1            1
1       2            1
2       3            1
3       4            0
4       5            1
```

the wanted result is as follows :

> df

```
      value      condition
0       1            1
1       3            1
2       6            1
3       4            0
4       9            1
```

If i loop over the dataframe as described in this post [Python pandas cumsum() reset after hitting max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132757/python-pandas-cumsum-reset-after-hitting-max)
 i can achieve the wanted results, but i was looking for a more vectorized way using pandas standard functions

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
df['cSum'] = df.groupby((df.condition == 0).cumsum()).value.cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   value  condition  cSum
0      1          1     1
1      2          1     3
2      3          1     6
3      4          0     4
4      5          1     9
```

You'll group consecutive rows together until you encounter a `0` in the `condition` column, and then you apply the `cumsum` within each group separately.

Comment: This is the exact problem I am trying to sovle, however the accepted solution raises an error in the current version of pandas. Do you know how to fix that ?